Eclipse Scout/Zebra Enterprise Browser, javascript namespace conflict
my problem is, I have in Eclipse Scout, javascripts from Zebra for the Enterprise Browser.
At first I had the javascripts directly in the project and loaded the required scripts in the head.html.
Now I wanted to load this internally via the Enterprise Browser, which also works with a configuration in a config.xml. However, this causes an error that I don't quite understand.
Error:
"ERROR org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.html.json.JsonMessageRequestHandler.handleLogRequest(JsonMessageRequestHandler.java:287) - JavaScript exception occurred
Uncaught namespace definition conflict! at http://[ip-address]:[port]/:1"
In this error, the :1 is actually the line of a file where the file name is missing. However, this file no longer exists because I am now loading the file myself via the Enterprise Browser. So where does this error come from?
When I insert the file again, the error appears with the specific path and file.
"http://[ip-address]:[port]/[path]/ebapi.js:1"
But this only happens in the Enterprise Browser because I am now only loading the scripts there. Even if I load all scripts in Eclipse Scout, no error occurs.
Only if I allow automatic injection in the config.xml:
  <InjectEBLibraries>
    <JSLibraries value=“1”/>
  </InjectEBLibraries>

Then the error occurs when I want to start the application via the Enterprise Browser, and only when I am in the application itself, the error does not occur when logging in or logging out.
Does anyone have any idea what the problem is, because I'm at a loss now.
Greetings Felix

I think I have found the problem.
When I load it with the Enterprise Browser Config, both the api module and the api file are loaded, which causes the error. So I load the javascripts as before.
